# How many times i may force Ubuntu to shutdown with no problems?

Tags: shutdown, crash, restart

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 on TBOX810-838-fl, this device is only be off by disconnect the power. the shutdown command does not work as SHUTDOWN it will work as RESTART.
I want to ask how many times Ubuntu can be forced to turn off and restart again with no problems nor crashed system.
Does forced-shutdown affect Ubuntu?
If it is working on the next boot fine and nothing happened nor crashed does that mean there is no problem?
Is there any specific Ubuntu version that can handle this more than others?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.    Why not use SysRq commands to shutdown safely; as it allows a clean shutdown.

Comment: I have shutdown systems many times without issue, other times issue occurs. Yes it's very predictable if you know what the machine is doing, however it's never worth the hassle of pulling a power cable; given the kernel provides a means to shutdown a crashed gui/system providing the kernel hasn't panic'd  A correct shutdown allows a clean next boot, even if terminal or GUI sessions are dead.  Use SysRq commands.  The kernel/release makes little difference (though some kernels can have SysRq disabled), it's more what you're running & doing with the machine, what hasn't been `sync`'d to disk

Answer (score 1):

A system that boots after a forced poweroff may still have other problems - unwritten or corrupted data, orphaned inodes and other filesystem corruption, and other possibilities. Each time is a fresh roll of the dice, a fresh chance of crippling damage.

NEVER poweroff a running system with a working kernel and mounted filesystem if you can possibly avoid doing so.

If shutdown (equivalent to `sudo shutdown --poweroff`) does not work,
then use halt (`sudo shutdown --halt`) instead to unmount the filesystems and gracefully stop the system before manually powering off.

- Run the command from a real tty (like `CTRL+ALT+4`), not a desktop-session terminal.
- Do not poweroff before your terminal indicates that the system is fully halted.